# wishing to allow access to one internet site only via openvpn

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, openvpn, nat

we have openvpn at work. it allows connection in and around the network with no issues at all. we've chosen not to push the default gateway so the staff connect use their own gateways to get internet. however one site they use is irn and the account allows access only though work's static ip address. for tor that site and that site alone we wish to allow internet access through the vpn. we are using ubunto with iptables and openvpn. so how would i do  this?
Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Franky and welcome on ServerFault. Please keep in mind that questions here should demonstrate "reasonable information technology management skills", and your question actually does not. Basically, you want to push a different configuration to just one client. There is plenty of documentation about how to do this if you just `man openvpn`, read their site, or even just search the right words. In your place I would consider deleting this question, before downvotes/closing votes comes.

Answer (score 0):

You can push a static route for this host only.

In your `my-vpn-server.conf`:

```
push "route A.B.C.D 255.255.255.255 W.X.Y.Z"
```

Where `A.B.C.D` is the IP address of the web server you want to access through the OpenVPN, and `W.X.Y.Z` is the IP address of your gateway, which will forward (or NAT) the VPN traffic.

With this setup you will see something like this on the client side:

```
root@client:~# ip r l
(...)
A.B.C.D via W.X.Y.Z dev tap0 proto static metric 50
```

If this web service you want to access has a DNS based load balancing, you will need to push the routes for all of its IP addresses.

I assume your question was about routing a single host through the OpenVPN, not about setting up NAT on linux, so I will not cover the latter here.

Comment: Thank you  lakukaracza. that was very helpful. yes it was just about the routing. that NAT is already set up on the iptables config. although i need to fine tune that so it will only nat that web site too, or people will be able to add their own routes client side and the nat will let it in but i  already know how to do that bit. :)

Comment: Thanks. If the answer was what you expected, you may click the "accept answer" button. Good luck with the vpn!